# Protractor Handling exceptions; Asyncd pop up; Javascript

Tags: javascript, exception, testing, automation, protractor

```
try {
        element(by.xpath(//*[@id='tab-settings'])).click()  
        browser.sleep(6000)

    } catch (e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        element(by.xpath("//*[@id='actionbar']/px-button")).click()
        browser.sleep(6000)
    }
```

--> Here i am trying to click on an element setting, mentioned in try block.
But there is a non certain pop up which occurs at any point of time, mentioned in catch block. This pop up does not occur at a fixed given event.
When i try to run this code it fails when the pop up occurs. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the `click()` result with a error handling promise resolution function:

```
element(by.xpath(//*[@id='tab-settings'])).click().then(function () {
    browser.sleep(6000);
}, function (error) {
    element(by.xpath("//*[@id='actionbar']/px-button")).click()
    browser.sleep(6000);
});
```